# How to send a BufferedReader to JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp

I'm doing the code below sending a BufferedReader object to a JSP page via setAttribute, but this is not working because in JSP when printing it it just prints the last line of the file. How can I send it to the JSP?

```
file = new FileReader("C://file.txt");
BufferedReader save = new BufferedReader(file);

while ((sCurrentLine = save.readLine()) != null) {
    request.setAttribute("dfTargetDevice", sCurrentLine);
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted just keeps setting the dfTargetDevice attribute to whatever it reads, so when it hits the last line that's the value which it stays at. Read all data into a StringBuilder, and set the attribute's value to that.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

while ((sCurrentLine = save.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(sCurrentLine).append('\n');
}

request.setAttribute("dfTargetDevice", builder.toString());
```

Comment: In other words, the attribute is being overwritten every time through the loop

Comment: for any reason the webpage is not being displayed, it's in blank now. Doing this do not work: request.setAttribute("dfTargetDevice", builder.toString());, but doing this, as example, works: request.setAttribute("dfTargetDevice", "Test"); - I don't see any logs being generated. Any idea?